# Combining an SQL query of differing length

Tags: sql

I'm wondering how you would go about combining these two queries.

```
-- gets average sick leave for females for each job
SELECT AVG(SickLeaveHours) AS FSickLeave
FROM Employees
WHERE Gender = 'female'
GROUP BY Job
ORDER BY FSickLeave DESC;

-- gets average sick leave for males for each job
SELECT AVG(SickLeaveHours) AS MSickLeave
FROM Employees
WHERE Gender = 'male'
GROUP BY Job
ORDER BY MSickLeave DESC;
```

I've already tried using a subquery and union, but have had trouble since the column lengths are not the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to put the conditionals inside a `CASE` expression, and where the conditional doesn't match set the value to `NULL` to prevent it being part of the set that is `AVG`'d:

```
SELECT
    AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'female' THEN SickLeaveHours ELSE NULL END) AS FSickLeave,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Gender = 'male'   THEN SickLeaveHours ELSE NULL END) AS MSickLeave
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Job
ORDER BY FSickLeave DESC;
```

Comment: Case _expression_.

Answer (score 0):

User Outer Apply...

```
SELECT AVG(SickLeaveHours) AS FSickLeave,MSickLeave
FROM Employees
OUTER APPLY(
SELECT AVG(SickLeaveHours) AS MSickLeave
FROM Employees
WHERE Gender = 'male'
GROUP BY Job
ORDER BY MSickLeave DESC
) M1
WHERE Gender = 'female'
GROUP BY Job
ORDER BY FSickLeave DESC;
```